# Why does super().__new__ sometimes return type of parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I've defined a child class of the sympy Equality class

```
import sympy as sp

class PEq(sp.Equality):

    def __new__(cls, lhs, rhs=0, **options):
        a = super().__new__(cls, lhs, rhs, **options)
        return a
```

Followed by a bunch of custom methods. I've been using this class for awhile and it works absolutely fine.

Until today, when I passed it a different form of argument for `lhs` and `rhs`.

```
r = sp.symbols('x,y,z')
p, R, ell, t = sp.symbols('p,R,ell,t')
eq1 = PEq(2*ell*t, p*2*R*ell)
print(type(eq1))  # prints <class 'sp_phys.physics_equation.PEq'>
tau = sp.Matrix(3, 3, lambda i,j:sp.Symbol('tau_%s%s' % (r[i], r[j])))
eq2 = PEq(sp.MatrixSymbol('tau',3,3), tau)
print(type(eq2)) # prints <class 'sympy.core.relational.Equality'>
```

So for some reason, the `__new__` method can sometimes return a variable of type Equality, but only when the arguments are of a certain type (in this case matrix objects).

I don't understand why `super().__new__` would ever return something of the type of the parent class. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: That'd be specific to the implementation of `sympy.Equality`, and not your code.

Comment: `__new__` is just another method, and the `sympy.Equality.__new__` method can make its own decisions what to return.

Comment: You are hitting [this branch](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/ac72d1c51da64d06acf914202ddd274a46f93aae/sympy/core/relational.py#L470-L479), the `lhs` variable is your `sp.MatrixSymbol('tau',3,3)` and it has an `_eval_Eq()` method: `<bound method MatrixExpr._eval_Eq of tau>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sympy.Equality()` class has a [custom `__new__` method](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/ac72d1c51da64d06acf914202ddd274a46f93aae/sympy/core/relational.py#L450-L541), and delegates evaluation to the operands if they support evaluation directly.

The `sp.Matrix()` class supports such evaluation; it implements an `_eval_Eq()` method, so it is passed the other operand:

```
>>> sp.sympify(sp.MatrixSymbol('tau',3,3))._eval_Eq(sp.sympify(tau))
Eq(tau, Matrix([
[tau_xx, tau_xy, tau_xz],
[tau_yx, tau_yy, tau_yz],
[tau_zx, tau_zy, tau_zz]]))
```

In that case, `Equality.__new__` just returns the result of that evaluation, see [this section of the implementation](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/ac72d1c51da64d06acf914202ddd274a46f93aae/sympy/core/relational.py#L468-L479).

Either disable evaluation, or account for this option and re-wrap the returned value, or patch the `_eval_Eq` methods to produce your custom subclass.